# Compare value of a nested java bean

Tags: jess

I am trying my hands with JESS wherein I want to write a rule as following.

When order amount is greater than 1000 and customer is preferred and customer name matches to order name then do something.

My Order.java has following properties
int amount, Customer cust

And Customer.java is a plain bean class holding following properties.
string name, string address

I am not able to find a way wherein I can get the value of Order.cust.name and compare with Customer.name in JESS.

Can anyone help me here please?

I tried using following but not working out for me.

```
(defrule HelloCustomer "When customer is preferred and amount is greater than 1001"
  ?person1 <- (Customer)
  ?cust <- (Customer {isPreferred == true})
  ?o <- (Order{amount > (+ 1000 1)})
  ?person2 <- (Order(customerA))
  ?person2Name <- (Customer{name == (Order{customerA.name})})
  =>
  (modify ?o (totalAmount 1000))
  (printout t "Found two different " (call ?person2.customerA getName) crlf))
  (printout t "Found two different*** " ?person1.name crlf))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many of the details right but the fundamentals are mostly wrong. First, note that each “Customer” and “Order” pattern matches a new object; this might match as many as five different objects. Secondly, you’ll need to bind variables to slot values so you can test them in other slots. Lastly, you’ll need to make use of the “OBJECT” slot to retrieve the Java object represented by each of this patterns. Roughly, I think you want something like

```
(defrule HelloCustomer
  (Customer {isPreferred == true} (name ?name) (OBJECT ?customer))
  (Order {amount > 1001} (name ?name) (OBJECT ?order)) ;; Repeating variable binds these together
  =>
  ;; do something with ?customer and ?order
```

The Jess manual covers all of this, but you do have to read the whole thing. After all, you’re learning a whole new programming language.

Comment: Thank you for the response Emest Friedman-Hill. However, my questions is - how can we access order.Customer.Name. Basically, customer is an instance member of Order and I want to access customer name from it in the condition part. I was able to access it in the action part => like using (call ?person2.customerA getName) but not in condition part. Could you please help how we can do that?